# How to reach destination object in ModelMapper's AbstractConverter.convert() method

Tags: java, spring, mapping, modelmapper

I would like to map fields from `source` into the existing object `dest` via custom Converter. Could you please suggest a canonical way to reach out `dest` object from `AbstractConverter#convert()`

Please find the code below:

```
Source source = new Source(xxx);
Dest dest = new Dest(yyy);

modelMapper.addConverter(new AbstractConverter<Source, Dest>() {
  @Override
  protected Dest convert(Source source) {
      // here I need to access 'dest' object in order to manually map fields from 'source'
  });

modelMapper.map(source, dest);
```

Comment: Is the Dest object, a static object that will be a base for mutating with source?

Comment: @Ryan Dake yes. I updated the question to make it more clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to access the destination object you should not use AbstractConverter, but an anonymous Converter:

```
modelMapper.addConverter(new Converter<Source, Dest>() {
    public Dest convert(MappingContext<Source, Dest> context) {
         Source s = context.getSource();
         Dest d = context.getDestination();
         d.setYyy(s.getXxx() + d.getYyy()); // example of using dest's existing field
         return d;
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `Dest dest = new Dest(yyy)` into the body of new AbstractConvertor.

```
modelMapper.addConverter(new AbstractConverter<Source, Dest>() {

  private Dest dest = new Dest(yyy);

  @Override
  protected Dest convert(Source source) {
      // here I need to access 'dest' object in order to manually map fields from 'source'
  });
```